# ios8 with autolayout in tableview header is not working anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I used to be able to use AutoLayout in subviews of the view I assigned to `self.tableView.tableHeaderView` but it looks like this is not working anymore in iOS 8.

```
self.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, self.view.frame.size.width, 200.f)];

self.questLabel = [[CLAPaddedLabel alloc] initForAutoLayout];
self.questLabel.text = @"My label here";
self.questLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.questLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.questLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kCLAfontIMFellItalic size:19];
[self.tableHeaderView addSubview:self.questLabel];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableHeaderView;
```

My autolayout rules are set in `updateViewConstraints` and are not respected. Console shows no errors.

Comment: Are you providing the tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: method? A lot of default values from iOS 7 and earlier no longer seem to be present. I had an issue where table cells were rendering at the narrowest height that could bound the content until I set the cell height with heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: What layout constraints are you talking about? Between the header and the label? What does initForAutoLayout do?

Comment: @rdelmar https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout is where initForAutoLayout comes from. Any constraints are not set correctly, no warning in console.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try by setting constraints for width and height on your header view, this has never given me problems:

```
 self.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero()];

 //do your config for the labels on the header view

 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableHeaderView;
 [self.tableHeaderView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
 [self.tableHeaderView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: header attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant: self.view.frame.size.width]];
 [self.tableHeaderView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: header attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant: 200.0f]];
 [self.tableHeaderView setNeedsLayout];
 [self.tableHeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
```